# converting strings to literal directories

Tags: python, unix, ipython, cat

Using iPython, I am trying to loop over all text files in a directory, do some operation on each text file (cropping a portion of text file after the line beginning with "BEGIN"), and then save the results into another temp.txt. However, when I do `!cat file_path`, it doesn't take `file_path` as the directory and it interprets it as a string named `'file_path'` instead. Is there anyway that I can convert the string `file_path` to literal directory that it can be used by `!cat`?

```
import os
for fn in os.listdir('./dir'):
     if fn.endswith('.txt'):
        file_path='./dir'+fn
        print "file path is:", file_path
        !cat file_path | sed -e '1,/BEGIN/d'>temp.txt
```

Outputs:

```
file path is: ~/Documents/dir/doc.txt
cat: file_path: No such file or directory
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can't just insert `!cat` to escape out and do a shell command. You'd have to use `subprocess.Popen` or something like that. Why not just do the cropping with python, or do it all in the shell instead of trying to mix them in this way? (This also has a "useless use of cat") Is this IPython and that is why the `!` works? You probably don't want `/Documents` but `~/Documents` I would guess?

Comment: I found it cleaner this way to mix both. But yeah it's possible to do it in just Python/Unix. And yes this is iPython and it's possible to switch over unix at any point using ! character and the correct directory is ~/Documents.

Comment: Maybe add the tag `IPython`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enclose `file_path` in curly brackets to mark it as a Python expression. Try this as last line of your script:

```
!cat {file_path} | sed -e '1,/BEGIN/d'>temp.txt
```

Comment: @Peyman glad I could help! Feel free to mark my answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark so I can reap those sweet reputation points :)

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion you forgot to add "/" in the file_path variable:

```
import os
for fn in os.listdir('./dir'):
    if fn.endswith('.txt'):
        file_path='./dir/'+fn
        print file_path
```

By the way in this case you can use bash:

```
for i in `ls ./dir`; do if [[ $i == d*.txt ]]; then cat ./dir/$i | sed -e '1,/BEGIN/d'>temp.txt ; fi; done
```

Comment: the lack f ```/``` is fine as I had it included in ```dir``` itself. I also wanted to use a combination of Python and Bash due to the requirement of the rest of the code which I didn't include here :)